# Windows Store App Multiline Textbox New Line

Tags: windows, xaml, textbox, windows-store-apps, multiline

I am creating a Windows Store App in C# and XAML with PRISM and it is more or less an email service.  I have a Textbox as the tool I use to type into.  The problem I am facing is that it seems not to register new lines.  This does not mean I cannot hit enter, it just won't show up when I send the message.  Here is the code I have for the Textbox in the XAML.

```
<TextBox IsSpellCheckEnabled="True" AcceptsReturn="True" IsEnabled="True" IsTextPredictionEnabled="True" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Text="{Binding Message.Body, Mode=TwoWay}"  TextWrapping="Wrap" >
```

This is an example of what will happen if I write something like this:

"Test

Test

Test "

It will show up like this:  "Test Test Test"

When drafting a message, it looks right, however once it is is not reading it correctly.
Would there be a workaround or a property I could change to make this TextBox work?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Have you tried this one yet ? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17684447/windows-store-app-multiline-textbox-new-line

Comment: @Vickel: You could add the correct store/marketplace tags, not just remove them

Comment: Isn't it just a newline character translation issue? For instance, your newline is encoded as System.Environment.NewLine, but the email service supports <br/>, or chr(10), etc.?

Answer (score 1):

TextBox wrapping means that when the line is too long it will wrap it.

If you want to enable users to write multiple lines into textbox you should use [RichEditBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br227548)

```
<RichEditBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
```

Comment: I tried removing the Wrap and that does not seem to solve my problem.  I have used the Rich Edit Box before although I found it extremely hard to find a way to bind to it because there is no "Text =" attribute.

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/f9a83d4e-26e9-476b-8818-7ccdf91a2341/richeditbox-mvvm-pattern here's sample on binding richEditBox